# Call a method in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

Currently my code is like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any) {
  this.showLockedWarning(nextProps);
}
```

but due to the `componentWillReceiveProps` getting deprecated, I'd like to use the function that has no such problems and as far as I see, I should have 2 options - `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `componentDidUpdate`.

I can't use `componentDidUpdate` because that creates an infinite loop, but from `getDerivedStateFromProps` I can't access `this` keyword. What could I do in this case?

Comment: Will you be changing state in `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not changing state (as in the example), then it would be better to move the code to `componentDidUpdate()`, but if you need to change state *and* call a function, then you could make the function you want to call `static` as well.